# Rails Paperclip, Multiple of Different Type (PDF, Image, Doc...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload, paperclip

There are a lot of good resources out there that show how to create a Rails application with multiple image uploads. Additionally, there are a lot of good resources showing how to use paperclip to upload different file types (PDF, image, .Doc).

I'd like to create an application where a User has an image asset for their profile picture, and also has the ability to upload PDFs or .Doc files to their account to be tied to the User. Has anyone had experience with this to confirm it's possible through the Paperclip gem? Any tutorials or resources to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Your words: "...there are a lot of good resources showing how to use paperclip to upload different file types (PDF, image, .Doc)."

Comment: Those tutorials only cover single file uploads of PDFs. Not multiple file uploads of different types, and how those resources are managed in form uploads, controller, etc.

Comment: I also have same problem... :(

Comment: got the solution.... posted it below...

Answer (score 8):

I was also having exactly same problem like you. No need to do extra coding for this, just add following

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
                    :styles => lambda{ |a|
                                  ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg", "image/gif"].include?( a.content_type ) ? {
                                  :thumb=> "100x100#",
                                  :small  => "150x150>",
                                  :medium => "300x300>",
                                  :large =>   "500x500>" }: {}
                                 }
```

Let me know if you need further explanations.

Comment: Thanks RAJ, this is interesting stuff. My core problem however is to find a way to incorporate both images and documents into it. So, a User could have an uploaded profile picture, and a user could also have a resume document (word document) uploaded to their account.

Comment: yeah as I said, I were having same issue...   just follow my code it will store 5 sizes (including original) for images and only original document for another files like .doc, .pdf etc

Comment: Thanks.. but do we have an option for showing some specific icon for other formats. like for pdf we show icon1, for .doc we show icon2

Comment: As I understand, you want to store icons for some other specific extensions. If it is, you can use nested conditions or switch (case) for specifying different styles as per extension.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thank you so, so much, this issue was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone is looking at this recently, we have just tried the accepted answer, and the content types did not work properly. We got it working like this:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, styles:  lambda { |a| a.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(image) ? {:small => "x200>", :medium => "x300>", :large => "x400>"}  : {} }
```

The difference is in the "column name" for the object -- typically "*_*__content_type", instead of just "content_type"

Answer (score -1):

You sure can upload images and other filled with paperclip, may be worth going to www.railscasts.com as there are quite a few related posts to your question.

Comment: I've already viewed the Railscasts and am familiar with the other major tutorials. The tutorials cover other file types, or multiple uploads of the same file type, but not both - and when implementing both, many complications arise.